# prototype for overloaded function in c++

Tags: c++

Why can't I give the prototype for an overloaded function in `main()` just like we do for other functions ?? for example I wrote the following code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
 void a(float);
 void a(float,float);

 a(2.4);
 a(5.6,7.4);

getch();
}

void a(float x)
{
 cout<<x;
}

void a(float y,float z)
{
 cout<<y<<z;
}
```

on running this code the turbo c++ compiler is giving an error, I have observed that it is ignoring the second declaration of the function `a` i.e. `void a(float,float);` and is therefore giving the error extra parameter in call to `a(float)`.

Comment: Have you checked the age of Turbo-C++? Some of the releases are from the early 1990's and not exactly current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked well on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ss0DxFLHLFVga0Lq).

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<conio.h>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
 void a(float);
 void a(float,float);

 a(2.4);
 a(5.6,7.4);

//getch();
}

void a(float x)
{
 cout<<x;
}

void a(float y,float z)
{
 cout<<y<<z;
}
```

It seems that your compiler is not so smart. Consider using another compiler.